# emberjs | save state of routes and nested resources

Tags: ember.js, routes, router

i am trying to build my first emberjs app and i wonder how i can save the state of a nested route to rebuild that state when the top route is revisted in the current session.

To give an example:

Lets Say a user switches from  **/overview/item1** to **/info** and then returns to
**/overview/** and want to redirect him to **/overview/item1**

HTML

```
<div id="navigation">
   {{#link-to 'info' class='link' }}Info{{/link-to}}
   {{#link-to 'overview' class='link'}} Overview {{/link-to}}
</div>
```

JS

```
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.route('info'); 
    this.resource('overview', function () {
        this.resource('item', { path : '/:item_id'});
    });
});
```

it would be really nice if somebody could give me a hint to the right approach of this.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways for achieving your goal. Basically, you need to store state of last visited `overview/:item_id` route in the parent route or controller. Then, you need to check this state before resolving model of `overview` route. If state is not null (user was selected some item from `overview/:item_id`), abort current transition and start the new one (to 
`overview/:selected_item_id`).

Schematic solution in code:

```
// 1st approach

App.OverviewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

    selectedItem: null
});

App.OverviewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    beforeModel: function(transition) {
        if (this.get('controller.selectedItem')) {
            transition.abort();
            this.transitionTo('overview.item', this.get('selectedItem'));
        }
    }
});

App.OverviewItemRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    afterModel: function(model) {
        this.controllerFor('overview').set('selectedItem', model);
    }
});

// 2nd approach (less code)

App.OverviewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    beforeModel: function(transition) {
        if (this.get('controller.selectedItem')) {
            transition.abort();
            this.transitionTo('overview.item', this.get('selectedItem'));
        }
    },

    setupController: function(controller) {
        controller.reopen({ selectedItem: null });
    }
});

App.OverviewItemRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    afterModel: function(model) {
        this.controllerFor('overview').set('selectedItem', model);
    }
});
```

It's important to keep the item itself, not it's id, because it'll way more easier to load `overview/:item_id` route in the future (passing stored model in `this.transitionTo('overview.item', item)`).